# Jquery mouseover dynamic p tag expansion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[this is another question related to something i posted earlier]

I have a p tag inside an anchor, there many be a variable number of instances of this during the loop. My goal is to on hover make the p tag expand and show more information. I have this so far in terms of mouseover.

```
$('.boxOPToneplustwo').mouseover(function (e) {
console.log("in");
$('p', this).addClass('popupHighlight')
});
```

I need to edit this code to allow the p tag to increase its height in relation to the amount of text in the element. if it needs three lines it will expand that amount and vice versa.

```
.popupHighlight {
height: 3.6em !important;
}
```

As you can see it is hard coded at this point to a certain height, is there a away to get around this issue?

Comment: Set the height to auto ?

Comment: that works, however the transition i applied earlier stops working, do you know why? thanks again adeneo, your a life saver today :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by setting some values in css

```
.popupHighlight {
     min-height:100px;

         overflow:hidden;
}
```

it will expand according to the size of the content

Answer (score 1):

Hey this thing is very easy to do.
Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/robbiebardijn/vAyn9/

```
.boxOPToneplustwo{
    background-color: red;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease
}

.boxOPToneplustwo.popupHighlight{
    height: 3em;
}
```

Comment: of course don't forget the vendor prefixes if you don't precompile your css.
I just quickly made an example.

Comment: also if you want this to be dynamic you should calculate the height with jquery. you can do this with the `.height()` function